# how to display range of dates in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I was just wondering how you can echo a range of dates in PHP

ideally i want the system to display this week wednesday to next week wednesday

for example

`17/11/10` to `24/11/10`

can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$oBeginDate = new DateTime('last wednesday');
$oEndDate   = new DateTime('next wednesday');

echo $oBeginDate->format('d/m/Y') . ' to ' . $oEndDate->format('d/m/Y');
```

Answer (score 2):

i see no mention about mysql in your question, but if you're really talking about it:

```
select * from my_table where date_fld between '17/11/10' and '24/11/10'
```

Comment: wow you have thought ahead of me aha. but the dates would have to update each wednesday, they are not fixed.

Comment: ... where date_fld between now() and now() + INTERVAL 1 WEEK

Answer (score 1):

create a date, and add days to it...

```
$m= date("m");
$de= date("d");
$y= date("Y");

for($i=0; $i<8; $i++){
  echo date('d-m-y:D',mktime(0,0,0,$m,($de+$i),$y));
  echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: this works great but i would like it show only this week wednesday and next wednesday dates in this format: "17/11/10 to 24/11/10"

Answer (score 1):

use strtotime

```
$now = '17/11/2010';
$next_week = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+1 week', strtotime($now)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since MySQL is tagged...

```
SELECT   now(), 
case
when weekday(now()) = 3 then date_sub(now(), interval 1 day)
when weekday(now()) = 2 then curdate()
when weekday(now()) = 1 then date_add(now(), interval 1 day)
when weekday(now()) = 0 then date_add(now(), interval 2 day)
when weekday(now()) = 4 then date_sub(now(), interval 1 day)
when weekday(now()) = 5 then date_sub(now(), interval 2 day)
when weekday(now()) = 6 then date_sub(now(), interval 3 day)
end as current_wednesday,
case
when weekday(now()) = 3 then date_add(now(), interval 6 day)
when weekday(now()) = 2 then date_add(now(), interval 7 day)
when weekday(now()) = 1 then date_add(now(), interval 8 day)
when weekday(now()) = 0 then date_add(now(), interval 9 day)
when weekday(now()) = 4 then date_add(now(), interval 5 day)
when weekday(now()) = 5 then date_add(now(), interval 4 day)
when weekday(now()) = 6 then date_add(now(), interval 3 day)
end as next_wednesday
```